# C# Timer -- measuring time slower

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing a code where:

I.)

The user adds "events" during run-time. (To a flowlayoutpanel) These events are turning some LEDs on/off, after "x" time has elapsed and the LED-turning functions are written in a Led-function.cs class.
i.e:
1) Turn left led on  After 3500ms
2) Turn right led on  After 4000ms

II.)

When the user hits start a timer starts.

```
            // Create timer.
        System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = (1);
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { HandleTimerElapsed(LedObject, device, _timer); };
        _timer.Start();
```

III.)
The timer's tick event is raised every millisecond and checks if the user definied time has ellapsed. Im measuring the elapsed time with adding +1 to an integer at every tick event. (NumberOfTicks++;)

```
        //Timer Handle
    private void HandleTimerElapsed(Led_Functions LedObject, string device, System.Timers.Timer _timer)
    {

        NumberOfTicks++;
        if (NumberOfTicks >= Start_time[0])
        {
            LedObject.LeftLED_ONnobutton(device);
        }
    }
```

IV.) What I noticed was that when the tick was set to 1. (So the tick event is raised every millisecond) Even if I set 3000ms to the evet the LED actually flashed around 6 seconds.
When the tick was set to 100. (So every 0,1s) then the flash was more accurate (3,5sec or so).

Any Ideas why im having this delay in time?
Or do you have any ideas how could I implement it better?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply set `_timer.Interval = userDefinedMilliSeconds;` and in  `HandleTimerElapsed (...) { LedObject.LeftLED_ONnobutton(device); _timer.Stop(); }`?

Comment: Thread context switching takes ~40ms, so trying to get finer grained resolution than that is going to be challenging. Maybe have a look at [the multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1ms is a really small interval for CPUs. You cannot ensure your code get called every 1ms especially when the system has some heavy work to do.

A better implement is to use `DateTime.Now - startTime` to get the time span or use `Stopwatch`.

```
private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
// start the stopwatch:
stopwatch.Start();
// Timer Handle:
numberOfTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case I dont have an event at any given interval am I right? Basically what i want to do is to fire some functions/methods after the user specified time has elapsed. (Sry im newb to C# and to programming)

Comment: Well in that case `Timer` is fine to use. Just don't use it to measure time span.

Comment: Then how should I implement the whole thing. The problem is I have to measure the elapsed time AND I have to be able to raise events at specific times...

Comment: Do both. Use `Timer` to raise events at specific times and use `Stopwatch` to query elapsed time or record start time to calculate elapsed time when needed. If your interval is long enough, you should try using `TaskScheduler`.